# Optimise and speed up very slow Linq / SQL code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I have the following C# method which I use to pre-load a data table of stock.  Although it works very well, now I have many rows in the table, it can be very very slow to load.

Please can someone recommend a better and much faster way to do this?  (Ideally to remove the "foreach" code as this is the slow bit!).

```
public static DataTable GetProducts()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    using (DataClassesDataContext data = new DataClassesDataContext(cDbConnection.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        var query = (from p in data.Products
                     where p.Deleted == false
                     join s in data.ProductStocks on p.ProductID equals s.ProductID
                     group s by p into g
                     select new { g });


        table.Columns.Add("Barcode", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Stock Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Tax", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Stock", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Service Item", typeof(bool));
        table.Columns.Add("Deduct Stock", typeof(bool));

        if (query != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                try
                {
                    decimal? Tax = 0;
                    if (item.g.Key.ProductTax != null)
                    {
                        Tax = Common.Utilities.IsValueValidDecimal(item.g.Key.ProductTax.TaxRate, 0);   // Tax
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Tax = 0;
                    }

                    bool DeductStock = !Convert.ToBoolean(item.g.Key.ServiceItem);

                    string[] row = new string[] 
                    {
                        item.g.Key.EANCode.ToString(),       // Barcode
                        item.g.Key.OurStockCode.ToString(),  // Product Code
                        item.g.Key.Description.ToString(),   // desc
                        GetGUIDisplayPrice(item.g.Key.RetailPrice, item.g.Key.RetailPriceExVAT),  // cost
                        Tax.ToString(),                         // Tax   
                        item.g.Sum(s => s.QtyOnHand).ToString(), // Stock
                        item.g.Key.ServiceItem.ToString(),   // Service Item (non-stock)
                        DeductStock.ToString()                  // if not a service item, the its a stocked item so deduct!
                    };

                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }//ENDIF NULL
    }//END USING

    return table;
}
```

Comment: What does your profiling show? Is it slow on the db on in this code?

Comment: what is the code of Common.Utilities.IsValueValidDecimal ?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code before you post - look at the question you're about to post, and ask whether it's formatted how you'd want to see it if you were going to answer.

Comment: var query = (query).toList().. This will load all the data to the query variable, Which i think should improve the performance when you do the iterations.

Comment: is this linq to sql or entity framework?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I am basically trying to see if I can replace the Foreach with Linq so that I can perform all the calculations on the server instead of for each row from the table.  

I have limited sql / linq knowledge and this basically written from advice I have got form this in previous questions and trial and error!

Comment: Jon Skeet - How do you suggest I format the code? I think my code is perfectly formatted for this question!  Your suggestions would be greatful?

Comment: Fredou - this function checks for a valid int (i.e. not null),  the code is linq to sql.

Comment: Richard - This is something I do not know and something I have never done before?  (time for google!)

Comment: @ViswasMenon: var query = (query).toList() doesn't speed up anything. It might slowdown the process, because you want to stream the results instead of fetching it complete.
@Belliez: why do you use a nullable decimal? Tax.ToString() will fail on null. Also `select new { g }` should be replaced with `select g`. Try to move the `item.g.Sum(s => s.QtyOnHand).ToString()` into the query, so it is calculated serverside.

Answer (score 2):

```
from p in data.Products
                 where p.Deleted == false
                 join s in data.ProductStocks on p.ProductID equals s.ProductID
                 group s by p into g
                 select new { g }
```

What is the schema of the Products and ProductStocks tables? What indexes do you have? start by reading [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Some things stand out immediate:

- you are fetching all the data from the server on the client. Don't. Process on the back end.
- using a `Deleted` bit field is a recipe for (performance) disaster. You can add it a clustered index leftmost key, with dubious results at best. Partitioning by can help, but not much. There is no silver bullet. Try to eliminate this requirement. Delete the deleted rows.

There is not much room to optimize. Stop fetching all the data.

Comment: Thank you, I gathered this would be the response. I will look into processing on the server instead of the client.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this function was turned into a stored procedure and the stored procedure returned the table that was created on the server, not the client. This was almost instant and massive performance improvement!